# Hide logs of successful tests

Tags: java, maven-3, slf4j, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

I am running my tests using Maven's Surefire plugin. My code has logging implemented using the SLF4J framework.

How do I disable displaying logs during `mvn test` for tests that complete successfully? I've seen this feature in `py.test` and would like to replicate it in a Java codebase.

Comment: could you elaborate on, for successful tests what all do you end up logging and you what you want to get rid of?

Comment: @nullpointer, I'm sorry, I can't parse your question...

Comment: What level of logs are getting displayed for your successful tests? and what level do you want to filter them for? If thats what your question intend to ask.

Comment: your request does not make sense since the logger would need to know if the test will pass or not at the time your code writes the log, which is usually before the assert in your test is executed. So the only way I see is to integrate a time machine in you testing framework.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: …or do it the same way as `py.test` does, which is buffering the log messages and only releasing them into stdout when the test fails. That's one way it could work.

Comment: @nullpointer, currently all messages, including DEBUG, are displayed always. Which is pretty messy. I want to hide everything unless the test fails.

Comment: If I am not getting you wrong you do not want to display anything uness your your test fails. And then display what all has been buffered. But why would you want to do that? To what I understand, logging is better a real time event for us to monitor it. Or the other way logging to a file should not be a concern in terms of when you are logging it.

Comment: @liori *"or do it the same way as py.test does"* so you have a testing dependency to your python production code? What I could think of is to configure sfl4j at test time to use a test result aware wrapper (which you may have to write yourself) on top of log4j (or what ever logging driver you use) writing your own test result aware log4j appender would also be an option.

Comment: @nullpointer: if I run a battery of tests, I'm only interested in debugging the tests which fail. Why should I then get loads and loads of information on tests that work correctly?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: I don't understand why you assume I have a dependency on python? And yeah, I was thinking of something like your suggestion on test-aware log wrapper, I just don't know what's the Java practice on the topic, what are tools for doing so, best practices, etc.